# Static JS files with Google App Engine / Node.js standard environment from node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, yaml, google-appengine-node

I have read Google's documentation and a number of similar questions, and am not having any success adapting the answers to my issue. I am working with *Google App Engine* in a *Node.js Standard Environment* and already have much of my app working and correctly configured.

Now I am trying to use `npm` modules as library code for **BOTH** my server-side app, and a client-side javascript app I am serving as a static directory. For this example, consider the widely used `jquery` module, of course available in `npm`

I believe the issue is in my `app.yaml` file, distilled to the part relevant to this question:

```
handlers:
### THIS ROUTE IS NOT WORKING
- url: /client/shared/lib/jquery\.js$
  static_files: node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
  upload: node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery\.js$
  mime_type: text/javascript
### CLIENT-SIDE STATIC ROUTES ARE WORKING
- url: /client/shared
  static_dir: shared
- url: /client.*$
  static_dir: client
- url: /.*$
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

Of course, I have already run `$ npm install jquery`.
For example, from the "server-side" (my `app.js` file & friends), the following works perfectly:

```
import $ from "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
```

Importing from my own "shared" code also works from both client and server via:

```
import { whatever } from "../shared/<module>.js"
```

But when I deploy and browse to `https://<myapp>/client/shared/lib/jquery.js`, I get a 404 error..

The goal is to be to get jquery from my "client-side" static javascript files with:

```
import $ from "../shared/lib/jquery.js"
```

(Or an equivalent relative path for deeper modules in the directory tree.)

Jquery is perhaps not the best example, if it bothers you pretend I'm talking about the "pluralize" library. I intend to use plenty of other npm distributions of js libraries and share them between my "client-side" statically served javascript files and my "server-side" code imported/pointed to from `script:` routes in `app.yaml` and/or imports from `app.js`

Also, I know I can use a "bundler" - or a cdn - etc. and I may eventually in production, but according to all the documentation  this /should/ work. **A correct answer will actually show me how to make this work and/or teach me what I don't understand about the `static_files` and `upload` handler options in `app.yaml`, not suggest an alternative that is a large edit distance away from my current setup.**

Comment: You might consider using a bundler like Webpack for your frontend; this will improve your page load speed, and that's how frontend npm traditionally works.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "sharing code"? Are you talking something like isomorphism like NextJS (I doubt it)? I'm not sure why you'd use jQuery on your server...

Comment: jquery was a bad but sufficient example. If it helps you answer my question, pretend I want to use the "pluralize" library from npm in both client and server...  by sharing code I mean I want to make a folder full of js files that are importable in both my static client files and my server-side program rooted in app.js... not sure how to make that clearer than I did above by showing the intended import statements

Comment: So by shared code you mean libraries you're using both in the front and backend? (Not real code code you wrote that runs both on the server and client.)

Comment: Well, ideally both. I was planning to mount "my" shared code in /shared, and shared "libraries" in /shared/lib ... I don't see a reason I would need to separate them a opposed to making one a child of the other, but that would also be possible.

Comment: Okay. I would highly recommend using a bundler like Webpack for your frontend.

Comment: Webpack and similar tools destroy my ability to sanely develop and debug by combining files..  Right now my web-browser tells me the file and line number of a javascript error, and I can jump right there in my text editor. Webpack will make a `bundle.js` file and screw all that up... I agree it's useful for deployment maybe, but not for development? Unless there is something key I am missing? Again, this is a documented feature of `app.yaml` - you should be able to host a single javascript file, or a static directory at whatever route you want..

Comment: Ah, okay. Are you able to access `http://yourwebsite/path/to/some/lib.js` in your browser?

Comment: As I said in my post, no, that makes a 404 error for the script i'm trying to post out of node_modules. but yes, it works for seemingly everything else. maybe reread the end of my post if you are still interested

Comment: Can you check if this [documentation on app.yaml configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element) answers how `static_files` and `upload` works for `app.yaml` configuration?